# How to disable site suggested fee in metamask window using web3js version 4.0.3?

Tags: web3js

I used web3 v1.10.0 and I could disable site suggested fee on metmask confirm window. But after updating the web3 version to 4.0.3, the site suggested fee is visible again. Can somebody please tell me the way to disable site suggested fee in latest version?

```
    const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(erc20ABI, contractAddress);
    contract.methods
      .transfer(destinationAdrs, (depositAmt * 1000000).toString())
      .send({ from: sourceAdrs, gas: "21000", maxPriorityFeePerGas: null, maxFeePerGas: null })
      .then(function (receipt) {
        console.log(receipt);
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.web3js.org/guides/web3_upgrade_guide/x/web3_eth_migration_guide#web3ethsigntransaction) says

> All the API level interfaces returning or accepting null in 1.x, use
> undefined in 4.x

> In 1.x, for untyped, 0x0 and 0x1 typed transactions,
> maxPriorityFeePerGas and maxFeePerGas are set to null. For 0x2 typed
> transactions, gasPrice is set to null. In 4.x these properties are not
> present unless provided

So, try updating `maxPriorityFeePerGas` and `maxFeePerGas` to `undefined` instead of `null`. I think that would fix the problem.